# regarding running grep -r -H 'string' for identifying the location for a given string

Tags: linux, files, grep, directory, command

I have been trying to find all the occurrence for a given string `$DIR_DATA` under a given directory.

I used the following command `grep -r -H '$DIR_DATA'`, but it seems took forever without finishing the search. What are the problem of this and what is the better solution to solve my problem?

Answer (score 0):

The grep command you are trying looks incomplete.

grep -r -H '$DIR_DATA' - this command does not specify where to search.

grep -r -H '$DIR_DATA' . - This with ' . ' at the end of the command will run the command in the working directory.

grep -r -H '$DIR_DATA' * - This with ' * ' at the end of the command will run the command inside all the directcries there.

Comment: the question is tagged linux, assuming GNU grep, current directory will be searched by default when using `-r` option

Comment: Hi Sundeep, then why it runs so slow?  Thanks.